# Else statement Syntax error (Simple Calculator)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am currently trying to code a little Calculator, as I am learning python right now. My problem is, that it keeps outputting Syntax error at the else statement at the end and since I am still a beginner I dont know why. :(
[Code of my calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4PDv.png)

Comment: You'll need another `elif` statement here. After `else` no other condition can be checked (hence `else`).

Comment: I changed the else to elif but it still outputs Invalid Syntax and marks the elif red.

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: The last line seems to an extra indentation level out. Back it up a rank and change the last `else` there to an `elif` and it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `colon  :` with else

It should be `else: {your logic}`

[Here's an example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Update: Actually you do have the colon, but with a condition. That should be an `elif` and NOT an `else`

Change last `else` to `elif`, you dont necessarily need an else if there's no default check.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a couple of issues with your code.

1. You aren't converting between strings and integers and etc.  `"4" + "5"` is not `9`, it is `"45"` because it is combining the two strings.  But if you do `int("4") + int("5")` then you would get 9.
2. When doing an else statement, there is no conditions.

So, a basic **if, elif, else** would be:

```
a = "yay"
if a == "yay":
    print("a likes you")
elif a == "no":
    print("a doesn't like you")
else:
    print("a doesn't want to respond")
```

**Python 2.7**

```
print ("Welcome to your friendly Python calculator.  Use + for addition and - for substraction")
print ("This code uses period (.) for decmimals")

first = "Please enter your first number "
second = "Please enter your second number "

operator = raw_input("Please choose an operation (+ or -) ")
if operator == "+":
    num1 = input(first)
    num2 = input(second)
    print ("Result: " + str(num1 + num2))
elif operator == "-":
    num1 = input(first)
    num2 = input(second)
    print ("Result: " + str(num1 - num2))
else:
    print("You didn't enter a valid operator.")
```

**Python 3.6**

```
print ("Welcome to your friendly Python calculator.  Use + for addition and - for substraction")
print ("This code uses period (.) for decmimals")

first = "Please enter your first number "
second = "Please enter your second number "

operator = input("Please choose an operation (+ or -) ")
if operator == "+":
    num1 = int(input(first))
    num2 = int(input(second))
    print ("Result: " + str(num1 + num2))
elif operator == "-":
    num1 = int(input(first))
    num2 = int(input(second))
    print ("Result: " + str(num1 - num2))
else:
    print("You didn't enter a valid operator.")
```